# Is the map from the space of Borel measure on $\mathbb{T}$ to the space of bounded sequences on $\mathbb{Z}$ non-surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle (or one-dimensional torus). I am looking to verify that the map
$$
\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T})\to l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z}) \\
~\mu\to\widehat{\mu}
$$
is not surjective where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T})$ is the space of Borel measures on $\mathbb{T}$, and $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{z})$ is the space of bounded sequences over the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

My initial thoughts were to find a contradiction. In particular, the Fourier transform is not defined on small sets (ie, of measure zero) so start by taking a Borel measure $\mu$ in $\mathcal{\mathbb{T}}$. What if this were measure zero? Would that produce an undefined Fourier transform $\widehat{\mu}$?

Comment: What do you mean by the Fourier transform "not defined on small sets"?

Comment: Also, do you want your measures to be positive and finite? (I assume you do, just making sure...)

Comment: You can restrict your attention to the class of idempotent measures. There are sequences of zeros and ones that are not Fourier-Stieltjes transforms of finite Borel measures.

Comment: @Lukas Geyer Yes, the measures are positive and finite. For a surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),~p>1,$ the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is defined almost everywhere, ie, not defined on a set of measure zero. Therefore, the Fourier transform is not defined on an arbitrarily small set.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The map $\mu \to \hat {\mu},$ from $M(T)$ to $l^\infty (\mathbb Z ), $ is 1-1. If it were onto, then the open mapping theorem would imply this is a Bananch space isomorphism. Thus

$$\|\mu\|_{M(T)} \le C \|\hat {\mu}\|_\infty$$

would have to hold. To contradict this, consider the measures $d\mu_n = D_n(t)\,dt,$ where $D_n$ is the Dirichlet kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You could show that there is no finite Borel measure corresponding to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lord_Farin The question is clear. To clarify my response, the Hilbert transform can be seen as a Fourier multiplier operator, where the multiplier is bounded. However, there is no measure with a Fourier transform that is equal to this multiplier. Therefore, the mapping is not surjective.